# Sl4a run Tasker Task and pass variable

Tags: java, android, arrays, sl4a, tasker

I try to start a Tasker task with sl4a and passing a variable %par1.

I have found some solution here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/tasker/Ayw-LhctQWg

It run the task "Test" but the variable %par1 isn't passed. Here the script:

```
import android

droid = android.Android()

task_name = 'Test'
par1 = 'test variable'

extras = {'task_name': task_name, '%par1': par1}

taskIntent = droid.makeIntent('net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK', None, None, extras).result
droid.sendBroadcastIntent(taskIntent)
```

The developer "pent" has answered the tip:

> ```
> extras = {'task_name': task_name}
> extras['varNames'] = namelist
> extras['varValues'] = valuelist
> ```
>
> I don't know python, but that looks like an array rather than an array
>   list (array list is a java dynamic array).

so I try to change the extras to:

```
...
task_name = 'Test'
varValues = 'test variable'
varNames = '%par'

extras = {}
extras['task_name'] = task_name
extras['varNames'] = varNames
extras['varValues'] = varValues
...
```

Now the same the task "Test" start but the don't passed.

The task is only to make a toast of %par1.

Here my script so far:

```
import android

droid = android.Android()

task_name = 'Test'
varValues = 'test variable'
varNames = '%par'

extras = {}
extras['task_name'] = task_name
extras['varNames'] = varNames
extras['varValues'] = varValues

taskIntent = droid.makeIntent('net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK', None, None, extras).result
droid.sendBroadcastIntent(taskIntent)
```

How to make a java dynamic array list to pass variables to tasker?

Answer (score 0):

I'd save the QPython variable to a file and read file with Tasker into tasker's variable.